# how to extract numbers from this echo into separate variables?

Tags: shell

Sorry about bits and snippit of information
So I am writing an average shell script program
so if use inputs

```
echo 1 3, .... | sh get_number
```

I would have to pull the numbers seperated by spaces from echo to be

var1 = 1, var2= 3, etc.

I tried

```
#!/bin/sh
sum=0 
for i in $* 
do 
sum=`expr $sum + $i` 
done 
avg=`expr $sum / $n`
echo Average=$avg
```

but doesnt work....
do I include a read here?
also how would I do 
`sh get_number <file1>, <file2>...` to grab numbers in them and sum them
in shell script?

Thanks

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: Are you incrementing `$n` somewhere?

Comment: `sum=$(( sum + i ))` should work in any POSIX shell; `expr` should no longer be necessary for arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for the `read` shell builtin:

`% echo "1 2 3 4" | read a b stuff

% echo $b

2

% echo $stuff

3 4`

Comment: Most shells will run the `read` command in a separate process, so `a` and `b` will not be available after that process exits.

Comment: go go zsh, then.  I would contend that "most" shells today, read is a shell built-in but yes it's not ancient bourn shell compatible. It was only didactic, in any case.  the read would be part of a larger shell script, right?

Comment: It's a shell built-in, but it's the pipe that induces a subshell to run the `read` command. There are exceptions (`zsh`, `ksh` I think, and `bash` with the `lastpipe` option in 4.2+), but it's not POSIX standard and therefore not portable.

Comment: that's what i meant by 'didactic'. if we have  echo 1 2 3 4 | average.sh, it's the 'average.sh' that will call read and do stuff to the variables.   I will edit my response to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1):

To fix up your code:

```
for i in $*; do
    sum=$(( sum + i ))
    n=$(( n + 1 ))
done
echo "Average=$(( sum / n ))"
```

Comment: 'read' is a red herring.  I blame my bad interpretation of the question.    Also, this answer works in dash so it'll probably work anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    (( i++ ))
    (( sum += $1 ))
    shift
done
echo "Average=$(( sum/i ))"
```

Note: This fails in `dash` which is the closest shell I could find to a *real* `sh`.

An example of reading values from files passed as command line arguments or from lines read from stdin:

```
add_to_sum() {
    set $*
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        I=`expr $I + 1`
        SUM=`expr $SUM + $1`
        shift
    done
}

I=0
SUM=0

if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    # process any arguments on the command line
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        FILE=$1
        shift
        while read LINE; do 
            add_to_sum "$LINE"
        done < "$FILE"
    done
else
    # if no arguments on the command line, read from stdin
    while read LINE; do
        add_to_sum "$LINE"
    done
fi

# be sure not to divide by zero
[ $I -gt 0 ] && echo Average=`expr $SUM / $I`
```

Comment: I just switched to sh and it still works here. I'll double check that sh is not aliased to bash.

Comment: I checked two centos systems and both had identical sh and bash shells. On an ubuntu system, sh is mapped to dash which caused my code to fail. On Mac OS 10.8.5 sh and bash are different binaries and the code works.

Comment: shucks... im using ubuntu system... also would you happen to know a way for this code to accept multiple input types?  so I can say sh averagesum <filename1> <filename2> which would cat "$@" it and then read the values in the file or accept echoed values?

Comment: You could read values from stdin if no parameters are passed to the script.

Comment: Does that automatically happen in sh? or do I have to write some specific commands.. I am a noob at this shell script

Comment: In a shell script you need to write the code. I'll post an example.